# Django : Calculated field + admin_order_field + action => FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword

Tags: django, django-admin

I am using django admin (1.11.x) and I defined a calculated field (_due_date_in_days) to display it as a column. I wanted to be able to sort of this column like regular fields.

I have a model class "Registration" that contains a date field "due_date" and a calculated field "_due_date_in_days"

```
def _due_date_in_days(self):
    return (now().date() - self.due_date).days
```

On the manager of class "RegistrationManager", I added an annotation

```
def get_queryset(self):
    qs = super(RegistrationManager, self).get_queryset().filter()
    return qs.annotate(_due_date_in_days=now() - F('due_date'))
```

In RegistrationAdmin I added format_due_date_in_days in the order list

```
def format_due_date_in_days(self, obj): 
         return (now().date() - self.due_date).days
    format_due_date_in_days.admin_order_field = '_due_date_in_days'
```

The sort on the calculated field is working well until I am using an action (https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/actions/) define on the ExampleAdmin class :

```
def mark_as_printed(self, request, queryset):
    rows_updated = queryset.update(is_printed=True)
```

When I am sorting on the calculated field AND I am using this action than error occured :

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword '_due_date_in_days' into field. Choices are: ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I my case there is a simple solution :

- remove the annotate
- define order_field on "-due_date"

The behavior will be the one expected

```
format_due_date_in_days.admin_order_field = '-due_date'
```